# write value from Servlet to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

heloo i want to write something from my servlet to jsp file. i did it using **requestdispatcher** but result didn't appear

here are codes:

**UserInfo.java**

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        DBUtils dbUtils = null;
        try{
            out = response.getWriter();     
            String username = null;
            String password = null;

            //setting cookies for session
            Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
            if (cookies != null) {
                for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                if(cookie.getName().equals("username"))
                    username = cookie.getValue();
            }
            }

            request.setAttribute("username", username);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("userinfo.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

**userinfo.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello ${username}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you pls explain `result didn't appear` ? did you get redirected to the page you requested (i.e) `userinfo.jsp`

Comment: on the place of ${username} theres nothing

Comment: i use ajax to redirect yo userinfo.jsp

Comment: Have you tried printing the `username` in your servlet to ensure it it `not null`

Comment: Check this documentation  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/java.817/a83726/basics4.htm

Comment: Where is your jsp file located? May be there is need to change path to "/WEB-INF/userinfo.jsp"?

Comment: value of username is not null because cookie exists. location didn't helped :(

Comment: Show us the folder structure and web.xml content, please.

Comment: heres structure http://tinypic.com/r/125m8zk/8

Comment: why you using request dipathcher with requerst object ?not with context

Comment: how it will be with context?

Comment: ServletContext context= getServletContext();
RequestDispatcher rd= context.getRequestDispatcher("/LoggedIn");
rd.forward(request, response);

Answer (score 0):

Try using `request.getAttribute("username")` in your jsp and include it <% %> tag.

Comment: still nothing appears

Comment: Try printing anything in your jsp. Does it appear? Maybe there's something wrong in your directories.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
ServletContext context= getServletContext();
RequestDispatcher rd= context.getRequestDispatcher("/userinfo.jsp");
rd.forward(request,response);
```

Note the difference when i am using **/userinfo.jsp**.. using it to provide the absolute path for jsp location. if there was no preceding "/" it will be considered for relative path and appends userinfo.jsp to existing request relative path.

OR if the above does not work rewrite this line to use absoulute path

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/userinfo.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 0):

use in your jsp no need to iterate

```
${cookie.username.value}
```